# Bootstrap - Is it possible to have a toggle push to the left effect in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle, slidetoggle

I am trying to make a website with Bootstrap with a vertical sticky navigation. Now, when my website is viewed on mobile devices, I wanna add a `toggle` `push` effect to it like shown in this pen: http://codepen.io/mathelme/full/dHIah

I just wanna know if it's possible to achieve with Bootstrap 3, if not I'll just make my own script. I am really new at Bootstrap and also kinda new to JS.

Any help is very much appreciated! :)

Comment: Bootstrap provides css for their components and js for their components, none of which are what you describe. If you can create your own css and jQuery then this can be done. I do it all the time, but I don't use Bootstrap because using their classes would require over-writing their styles and it's a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have absolutely nothing of your own and this is not a coding service either, so I'll give you the tools to do it: you can use (for example) [Google Nexus Website Menu](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/30/google-nexus-website-menu/) from Codrops tutorial and easily adapt it to Bootstrap or Foundation, I have done it for both, so I can promise you it's incredibly easy. As a tip, you'll see that `<div class="container">` which is like any `<div class="container">` in Bootstrap, and from there just change the content and menu width to `col-md-3` and `col-md-9` or whatever you need.

You could also use [this tutorial](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/YouTubeLeftSideMenu/) from the same site, which is equally easy, you just need to pay attention where you place the menu part, and eventually change the targeted div in your Jquery, but it's really easy, basically replacing those non-Bootstrap divs for Bootstrap divs and that's it.

Of course, these are just some suggestions, you could also use your own example as well, and there are thousands of way to do this, but if you don't know much about JQuery, guess these 2 tutorials will really help you since they work equally well for the experienced coder as for the novice